# Dynamic Range Based on User Input

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I am creating a dynamic array. Column A contains a key, using numbers 1-7. Columns B-K contain strings. The array is made by looping from 1 to the last row and for each loop there is an if statement checking the key to see if it is on the right row. Inside the if statement the value of column B is added to the array. I have working code for this, however I need the range that gets the value in column B to be dynamic so the code will have the same result except it will work for any row, based on user input, and not just column B. I have a dynamic userform list of radio buttons at the beginning of the macro that contains all of the column headers. The user selected column head (string value) is stored in "SelectedOption".

Below is my current code, any help making the "Range("B" & i)" part dynamic based on the user input would be appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To lRow
If Range("A" & i) = 4 Then
     ArrayTest(UBound(ArrayTest)) = Range("B" & i) 'this needs to be a dynamic range to get correct values in array
     ReDim Preserve ArrayTest(UBound(ArrayTest) + 1)
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting `SelectedOption` for `"B"` in your code?

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't work with the range format, so i changed to cells and created a range, posting working code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by declaring new range using cells(row,column). Finished code below:

```
For i = 1 To lRow
If Range("A" & i) = 4 Then
     Set arrayRange = Cells(i, SelectedColumn)
     ArrayTest(UBound(ArrayTest)) = arrayRange
     ReDim Preserve ArrayTest(UBound(ArrayTest) + 1)
End If
Next i
```